# How are channels sorted in a section in Slack?

Tags: slack

It says alphabetically:

[image]

However, it's not 100% alphabetically:

[image]

How are channels sorted in a section in Slack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reddit user [NastyCamper](https://www.reddit.com/user/NastyCamper) gave the [answer](https://redd.it/v8dad0):

> All of the ones at the bottom, which were the out of order ones, were muted channels in the same section. They were also a grey color (dark mode FTW) whereas the others had white lettering.

I confirm this explained my screenshot in the question.